# I predict Char array type value could cast pointer type only

Tags: c++

I predict char value type could cast pointer type only.
Am I right?

And what is those difference between Struct1 and Struct2?

Moreover, Somebody says it could be an error.

```
struct UdpReceive ReceiverA;    
UdpReceive ReceiverB; // <= It's supposed to be an Error.
```

But I couldn't make this happen in C++, then compile succeed.
Does this error happen only in C?
Thanks.

```
int main()
{
    //It will be assumed containd Byte data of UDP.
    unsigned char ReceivedData[128];
    //Struct pt1
    struct  UdpReceive {
        char name[20];
        int age;
        double hegiht;
    };

    UdpReceive ReceiveBuffer;
    UdpReceive* pReceiveBuffer;
    //Struct pt2
    typedef struct{
        char name[20];
        int age;
        double hegiht;
    }V2SUdpReceive, *V2SUdpReceive;

    V2SUdpReceive V2ReceiveBuffer;
    V2SUdpReceive* pV2ReceiveBuffer;


    pReceiveBuffer = (UdpReceive*)ReceivedData; 
    ReceiveBuffer = (UdpReceive)ReceivedData;// <= it's not pointer type that is reason why Error.

    pV2ReceiveBuffer = (V2SUdpReceive*)ReceivedData;
    V2ReceiveBuffer = (V2SUdpReceive)ReceivedData;// <= it's not pointer type that is reason why Error.

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @melpomene Hi, I'm asking about how to convert CharArray to Struct.

Comment: @GGMadFish, it didn't make it any cleaner. Define "convert".

Comment: @dynkha I mean cast, sorry I'm bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you could cast a char pointer to a struct.

In C++ you can do it as well, but you should not do it. Although it may work. But C++ gives you no guarantee about how the data of the struct is represented internally.

Your problem is called serializing / deserializing. You have struct and you want to send its contents over some connection to a other party. But the other party may have a different internal memory representation of such a struct. And the correct reception of the data would fail.

If you want to do it for yourself in none productive code, try the casting and, if it works use it.

Maybe better: Create some functions for serializing / deserializing, maybe overwrite the inserter >> and extractor operator <<. Or, use a common serilization framwork, which you can find on the net.